# VBA Módulo que armazena dado de uma célula e o move para outra célula e move para a célula de baixo

Tags: vba, if, foreach, excel-vba

Boa noite gente, eu criei uma pasta com macro onde eu tenho duas planilhas, Consulta e jogos.
Na planilha jogos eu coloquei nome de jogos e os seus respectivos valores em reais, já na consulta eu criei uma lista para fazer o autocomplete com caixa de combinação usando o PROCV.

Então, o que eu estou tentando fazer, obter o valor de uma célula que, obtém o seu valor da caixa de combinação e copia-la para uma outra célula que ao fazer isso, a seleção da célula vai para baixo, para assim que eu for selecionar outro jogo, ele irá copiar novamente o valor daquela célula para a nova.

Já consegui obter o valor e joga-la na outra célula, mas não sei como fazer para a seleção ir para a célula de baixo, já pesquisei e tentei usar o Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}" mas não funcionou, eu pensei em usar For each e consegui fazer pular a linha, mas depois disso não consegui fazer um jeito de obter o valor novamente.

Segue o código abaixo.

```
Sub teste()
Dim exame As String
Dim valor As Double
Dim limite, celula As Range


Set limite = Range("F2:F50")


    For Each celula In limite.Offset(0, 5)

        If Range("E4").Value <> "" Then
            exame = Range("E4").Value
            valor = Range("D5").Value

            Range("F2").Value = exame
            Range("G2").Value = valor

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Favor criar um [mcve] com exemplo dos dados que deseja realizar isso. Podendo criar uma [tabela](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) e quais erros ocorrem? E para melhor legibilidade, a [indentação pode ser realizada.](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation)

Comment: Então Daniel Takeshi, ignorando o For Each, no IF eu pego o valor dentro do E4, que será diferente de vazio, jogo os valores das células E4 e D5 e as jogos nas respectivos variáveis, exame e valor, depois elas serão movidas para as células F2 e G2. Eu pensei que usando o For Each, e colocando o Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", faria com que ao pegar os valores, o cursor iria para a célula de baixo, para assim pegar mais valores e colocando-os como uma pilha, entedeu?

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta com estas informações e alguns dados para teste? para ilustrar, pode ser por imagem

Comment: Assim, se eu usar o sendkeys {"ENTER"} ele dá enter no código e não na planilha. 
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/1-png-4439d924-b98a-4449-8232-b930f57b0364

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/2-png-09646f65-d78b-4820-83b7-225fb637b33d

Answer (score 0):

## SendKeys

O método `Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"` irá somente apertar a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> quando for chamada. Portanto, se o seu cursor estava no código VBA. Ela dará o comando de *New Line* no VBE.

## Problemas no Código

#### Declaração

A declaração está incorreta desta maneira:

`Dim limite, celula As Range`

Em que `limite` está declarado somente como `Variant` e `celula` como `Range`. O correto seria:

`Dim limite As Range, celula As Range`

(Sintaxe estranha que ocorre no VBA)

#### For Each

O For Each é escrito no código, mas em nenhum momento é utilizado.

```
For Each celula In limite.Offset(0, 5)
Next celula
```

Portanto, você não está utilizando o loop. Somente tentando escrever os valores de células individuais no mesmo lugar.

## Solução

#### Última Célula

Acho que entendi errado a questão, o que deseja é inserir valores abaixo da última Célula preenchida. Então o código seria este:

```
Dim exame As String
Dim valor As Double
Dim UltimaLinhaF As Long
Dim planilha As Worksheet
Set planilha = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("nome_da_planilha")

With planilha
    UltimaLinhaF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
      If .Range("E4").Value <> "" Then
        exame = .Range("E4").Value
        valor = .Range("D5").Value

        .Range("F" & UltimaLinhaF + 1).Value = exame
        .Range("G" & UltimaLinhaF + 1).Value = valor

    End If
End With
```

## Solução para múltiplas linhas em E

Para vários valores na coluna E

#### For Each

Uma solução com um loop em cada célula, da maneira que você está tentando fazer é:

```
Dim exame As String
Dim valor As Double
Dim limite As Range, celula As Range
Dim UltimaLinhaE As Long, contador As Long
Dim planilha As Worksheet
Set planilha = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("nome_da_planilha")

With planilha
    UltimaLinhaE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    Set limite = .Range("E2:E" & UltimaLinhaE)
    contador = 2 'Inicia na linha 2
    For Each celula In limite
        If celula.Value <> "" Then
            exame = celula.Value             'Valor na Coluna E
            valor = celula.Offset(, -1).Value 'Valor na Coluna D

            'Escrever os respectivos valores em F e G
            .Cells(contador, "F") = exame          'Escreve em F
            .Cells(contador, "G") = valor          'Escreve em G
            contador = contador + 1
        End If
    Next celula
End With
```

#### Autofiltro

```
Dim limite As Range
Dim UltimaLinhaE As Long
Dim planilha As Worksheet
Set planilha = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("nome_da_planilha")

With planilha
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    UltimaLinhaE = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    Set limite = .Range("E2:E" & UltimaLinhaE)
    limite.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"

    .Range("E1:E" & UltimaLinhaE).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("F2")
    .Range("D1:D" & UltimaLinhaE).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("G2")
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
End With
```

Comment: Nossa, sobre declaração, eu não sabia disso não. Sobre o For Each, eu fiquei com um pouco de receio de usar de maneira errada, que pelo visto foi. Isso porque eu ainda pesquisei. Sobre as soluções, olha, muito bom mesmo, eu estava vendo uma vídeo aula com o With/End With, mas tava na parte de alteração de valores e cores dentro da célula.Sou muito grato pela paciência e o ensinamento, estou estudando o seu código para que eu tenha uma noção melhor de como programar no VBA, caso eu tenha que fazer uma pergunta novamente, tentarei fazer uma pergunta mais clara. Muito obrigado Daniel